# NGINX rewrite dynamic url

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite, cache, confluence

I configure NGINX proxy cache for Atlassian Confluence

And i faced a problem of caching the edited pages

Some time after editing the pages do not show the changes(cache TTL)

I decided to force the clearing of NGINX cache after pressing the "Save" button

For that i used LUA script:

```
    location ~ /pages/editpage.action?pageId=87556693 {
            content_by_lua 'os.execute("find /var/cache/nginx/ -type f -delete")';
            return 302 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

But a got cycle redirections (obviously :)

I have 2 questions:

1. How to change `location ~ /pages/editpage.action?pageId=87556693` for dynamic url (numbers `87556693` can change)?
2. How to rewrite url `/pages/editpage.action?pageId=87556693` to `/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87556693` in `location` in NGINX? To get rid of cycle redirections

Im not good at regex

Thanks!

Comment: The location you show never match anything because query arguments are not part of the location matching.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, true -- unless `?` was URL-encoded as `%3F` as per the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470191/external-links-url-encoding-leads-to-3f-and-3d-on-nginx-server/21012310#21012310 :-)